# parse <script> tag with js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page where a user is able to edit a HTML resource (using ACE Editor). Within this HTML source, there is a `<script>`-tag, which does some pretty basic stuff.

Is there any elegant solution to parse the script tag in order to (e.g.) evaluate the variables used within the script tag? For "normal" tags I use parseHTML() to have the html as a jQuery object.

From this **example**, I would like to retrieve the value of $myVal (which is "*f00*") and write it to *#myLabel*:

```
<textarea id="myScript" rows="5" readonly>
  <script>
    $myVal = "f00";
  </script>
</textarea>
<label id="myLabel">Hello</label>


$(function(){
  $scriptVar = $('#myScript').text;
  // parse the $scriptVar
  // retrieve the value of, $myVal, write it to #myLabel  
  //$myParsedValue = ???
  //$('#myLabel').text('bar!'); 
});
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stepdown/jqcut0sn/

Is this possible at all? I don't really care about vanilla js, jQuery, regex or maybe even an external library for that purpose.

Comment: In such a primitive case you might be able to extract the value from the text content of the script element ... but what do you do, once the user starts entering stuff like `$myVal = "f"+"0"+"0";` …? Then you would have to _execute_ that JS first of all, if you are interested in getting the actual, final value that variable will have afterwards.

Comment: It should be `.text();` and I believe you can use `eval()` to execute stringified code. But......... beware of eval :)

Comment: The entered *script* is rather simple, in fact it is a number of variables which are then used to call a function. Therefore I want to parse the variables used within this function. I will take a look at `eval()`, being aware of its bad reputation. Thank you both so far!

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThille, `eval()` was a quite good starting point. I found `$.globalEval()`, which sort of serves my purpose. I need to remove the `<script>`-tag, then the script entered is executed correctly and I can access the used variables. I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stepdown/Lxz7q6uv/ - however I will leave the question unanswered for 1-2 days, maybe someone has a more beautiful solution. (Wondering about the uncommented downvote - is this question so bizarre?! Whatever. :))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeremyThille, who pointed me to the right direction. I found out, what I want to achieve is possible through jQuerys `$.globalEval()` - see the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/).

Basically what globalEval() does: it runs the script which is written in the `<textarea>` and makes the variables / functions globally accessible.

**IMPORTANT**: this implies, that syntax errors (etc) by the user will break the evaluation, and sequential functionality could be flawed. Also, the new variables are GLOBAL, so basically a user could rewrite scripts on the hosting page. (In my case both problems are of minor importance, since this is an internal application for trained users - they also have syntax highlighting through the amazing ACE editor. But I wanted to make sure to point it out. Also, there are several articles regarding the risks/ouch-moments when using eval()...)

I updated the fiddle to achieve what I wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/stepdown/Lxz7q6uv/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="myScript" rows="5" readonly>
   $myVal = "f00";
</textarea>
<hr />
<label id="myLabel">Hello</label>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
   var myScriptContent = $('#myScript').text();
   $.globalEval(myScriptContent);
   console.log($myVal);
   $('#myLabel').text($myVal); 
});
```